# Possible to specify UTC+3 to linux date when creating a timestamp string?

Tags: linux, date

I am trying to create a timestamp string:

```
  TS=$(date -d "today" +"%Y_%d_%m_%H%M%S")
  echo "TS = $TS"
```

But I need it to be in UTC+3. The man pages on date does not show that as an option and I don't want to modify the OS locale.

I have tried:

```
$ date -d "today" +"%Y_%d_%m_%H%M%S +0300"
2020_16_04_090342 +0300

$ date -d "today" +"%Y_%d_%m_%H%M%S +0400"
2020_16_04_090347 +0400
```

So seems it has no effect. Also the string should NOT contain the offset, should just be:

```
2020_16_04_120347
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no 'OS' locale; every process can have its own locale. But timezone isn't part of the locale, and each process can have its own timezone. Assuming the Olson/IANA naming used on most systems nowadays, `TS=$(TZ=Etc/GMT+3 date ...)`

Comment: That would have made a great answer, Dave

Answer (score 1):

`man date`

> DATE STRING
>   The **--date=STRING** is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers. An empty string indicates the beginning of the day. The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.

```
date -d "today" +"%Y_%d_%m_%H%M%S +0300"
```